# How to compress an FLV movie in java?

Tags: java, compression, flv

How can we compress the flv movie? Is there any free library which i can use?
for compressing the video i can go for reducing the resoultion as well, even framerate reducing is acceptable to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) to do exactly this, directly from Java.  Here's 3 lines of Xuggler's MediaTool API code that will transcode a file:

```
 // create a media reader
 IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader("videofile.flv");

 // add a viewer to the reader, to see the decoded media
 reader.addListener(ToolFactory.makeWriter("output.mov", reader));

 // read and decode packets from the source file and
 // and dispatch decoded audio and video to the writer
 while (reader.readPacket() == null)
   ;
```

See the tutorials and user groups and other examples for how to tweak encoding parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) a good place to start might be 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jffmpeg/
It's a Java wrapper for ffmpeg

Comment: but i guess this is a command line utility. it is not having any API or some sort of like that which we can use in our java code. am i right?

Comment: `that's a good thing` what do u mean by that dear! If it can't solve my problem then it is not a good thing ;). Though i think sooner or later i will have to accept your answer.

Comment: If you use java to open a shell and call ffmpeg to do it's work that way you'll have no problems with the gpl licence

Answer (score 1):

FLV is simply a container format - the actual codecs used within an FLV vary.  Additionally, the codecs themselves are patented, meaning there are legal barriers for using them.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video), FLV files likely contain video compressed using Sorenson Spark or VP6.  If you know which codec your movie uses, you might try finding a library that can work with it.

It's very likely, however, that there are already tools available for encoding or re-encoding FLV files which you might be able to use via JAVA or some other language.

Comment: Nifle's answer ties in with what I was saying :)